# Issue while editing connection string

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using following code to edit my connection string

```
Dim adapter As New dbSQLServerTestDataSet1.tblContact
Dim conn As New SqlConnection()
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & vrCompName & "\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\dbSQLServerTest.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
adapter.Connection = conn
Dim table As DataTable = adapter.GetData()
```

But it gives error on

```
Dim adapter As New dbSQLServerTestDataSet1.tblContact
```

on `dbSQLServerTestDataSet1.tblContact` part of the line.  These objects do exits in my project.  I have also imported `System.Data` and `System.Data.SqlClient`.

Please guide.

Comment: Type dbSQLServerTestDataSet1.tblContact not defined

Comment: Remove the New keyword and try again. Hope it will create the problem.

Comment: Please provide some more code. Where are you declaring dbSQLServerTestDataSet1. Does it contains tblContact?

Comment: I am adding it by adding Binding source and then making connection

Answer (score 0):

Add in the namespace

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

then use following code:

```
 Dim ds As dsTestCon

    Me.taTestCon.Fill(Me.DsTestCon.tblTest)
    MsgBox(DsTestCon.tblTest.Rows(0).Item(1))

    MsgBox(taTestCon.Connection.ConnectionString)


    Dim adapter As New dsTestConTableAdapters.tblTestTableAdapter
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection()
    Dim vrCompName As String = My.Computer.Name
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & vrCompName & "\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=e:\dbTest.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    adapter.Connection = conn
    Dim table As DataTable = adapter.GetData()
    MsgBox(adapter.Connection.ConnectionString)

    ds = New dsTestCon()
    adapter.Fill(ds.tblTest)

    MsgBox(ds.tblTest.Rows(0).Item(1))
```